# Allow \listoffigures captions to break across pages

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, page-breaking

I'm using the command `\listoffigures` to list all figure captions after the contents page. Many of my figure captions are quite long and as a result LaTeX is placing 2 captions on a page with a large gap in between them. I would like to prevent these gaps by allowing figure captions to be split across pages just like normal text would be - how can I do this? I am aware of the short caption option with `\caption[short]{long}` for long captions but this is not appropriate for my purposes.

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\newpage
\centering

\section{Section 1}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}

\section{Section 2}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}

\section{Section 3}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}

\section{Section 4}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

This creates an analogous problem to the one I have: in the list of figures, the third figure legend starts on a new page leaving a large space at the end of the second figure legend (bottom of page 1). How can I force the third figure legend to start on page 1 and finish on page 2 like normal text?

Comment: Can you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/32374) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @darthbith I have edited the question to provide an example of the problem.

Comment: Page breaking of caption is difficult, I suppose ;-)

Comment: My suggestion is to use the optional argument of `\caption` for a short version of the caption to go in the list of figures. An overlong caption in the list won't help the reader, who probably needs to see the figure in order to understand what the caption is describing.

Comment: I agree with egreg: The long caption is the right place to explain what is shown in a figure/table and the short version is intented for a quick look which figure/table has which content, although it might be tedious to find the correct short description sometimes. Long caption content in the `List of Figures` looks awkward, in my point of view.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I can't shorten some of the figure captions as they won't make sense to the reader - the contents are very technical (and different between chapters) and so need a bit of background, though I appreciate what you are saying. Shorter captions will reduce the problem, but won't get rid of it, i.e. there are still large gaps between captions even with shorter captions.

Comment: If they are so complicated, why bother with a LOF at all? Or if you want to list the page with each figure, set the short caption to empty maybe so you don't have to worry about confusing readers?

Comment: Some of them are complicated, not all of them. The list of figures is a requirement for the thesis I'm writing.

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX sets `\interlinepenalty` to the maximum value, 10000 while setting each caption in the LOF, if you locally disable  `\interlinepenalty` by defining it to be a scratch register, so that the value set is ignored then  page breaking happens as usual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

{\countdef\interlinepenalty255
\listoffigures

}
\newpage
\centering

\section{Section 1}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}

\section{Section 2}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}

\section{Section 3}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}

\section{Section 4}
\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```